# Не работает RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

я нубяра и только учу php, подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает "ЧПУ" ?
Windows Server, Локальный хост, апачи, стат. ip.

Выдаёт ошибку:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform
>   them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
>   just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

---

Сам аштиакссес:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
</IfModule>

ServerSignature Off
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteRule ^reg?$ reg.php [NC, L]
```

---

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ServerSignature Off
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks #Добавьте это еще
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^reg?$ reg.php [NC, L] 
</IfModule>
```

*UPD по комменту - правильность выражения `RewriteRule ^reg?$ reg.php [NC, L]` Вам нужно определить самостоятельно - не известно из Вашего вопроса, что и из чего Вы хотите получить.

Если нужен редирект всех файлов в папке на заданный файл,
то так
`RewriteRule ^reg(.*)$ /reg.php [NC, L]`

*По комменту - тогда так:

```
ServerSignature Off
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymLinks #Добавьте это еще
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
###Убирается расширение .php из адресной строки
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Я попробовал, всё тот же Internal Server Error выдаёт. Ничего не поменялось

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать так, что бы вместо url.ru/reg.php я, и вообще все люди могли написать просто url.ru/reg 
я прочел что это называется  "человекоподобные URL".
И написал данный код - однако выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Заработало!  причем не только с reg

Comment: Вот и хорошо, рад!)